# If {x,{x,y}}={z,{z,t}} then x=z and y=t must be?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Question* If {x,{x,y}}={z,{z,t}} then x=z and y=t must be?

My answer: Yes. Assume $x\neq y$. Then, {$x$,{$y$,$z$}} has two elements: $x$ and {$x$,$y$}. Thus, $x\neq z$ since {$z$,{$z,t$}} should have two elements. Therefore, $x=z$ and {$x,y$}.

What do you think about the question?

Comment: You got typos.$\,$

Comment: @GitGud I did not understand you.

Comment: What if x is allowed to be a set.? What if x = {z,t} while {x,y} = z?  Is that possible?

Comment: @fleablood Okey. Then, Since $x\neq z$ must not be, $y\neq t$ is not be, is it?

Comment: I don't know I haven't worked out the details.

Comment: I'm just giving you food for thought.  if x ={z,t} while z={x,y} you get x={{x,y},t} and z ={{z,t},y} which involve self nested sets.  Which can lead to russel's paradox.  In my day, self nesting sets were acceptable if we accepted we could define impossibilities we weren't careful and we were aware that just because something can be defined doesn't mean it's exists.  I get the impression mathematics has changed and self nesting is a strict no-no.

Comment: @fleablood Self nesting sets is not permitted in ZFC due to the axiom of foundation.  However they are permitted in set theories that have the axiom of anti-foundation.